# LiteDB incldue BsonDocument without mapping

Tags: c#, litedb, nosql

Is there an any way to include DbRef without mapping?

as like,

```
var chats = Database.db.GetCollection<ChatData>("Chats").Include(x=>x.User);
```

to

```
var chats = db.GetCollection("Chats").Include(x=>x["User"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's possible, in current master branch.

Use `db.GetCollection("Chats").Include("User")`

Include now support strings as path, like: "`User`", "`Customer.Address`"

Will be avaiable in NuGet in next release.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you litedb!